# 401 response when a POST request is sent to oauth/token from vuejs client

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

My spring app authentication works fine when I am using postman.
However, when I do it from my client I get 401 http responde.

I configured my server for cors as follow:

```
@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
            registry.addMapping("/*")
                    .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:8080")
                    .allowedHeaders("*")
                    .allowedMethods("*");
        }
    };
}
```

This is the post request from vue client:

```
    var params = new URLSearchParams();
    params.append('grant_type', 'password');
    params.append('username', 'username1');
    params.append('password', 'password1');

    axios({
      method:'POST',
      baseURL: `http://localhost:8088/`,
      url: 'oauth/token',
      auth: { username:'my-trusted-client', password:'secret' },
      headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:8080',
        "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8"},
      data: params
    }).then ((response) => {
      console.log (response)
    }).catch ((error) => {
      console.log (error)
    })
```

The response I am expecting is something like:

```
 {
 "access_token": "5766cc81-87e7-44c5-9aad-188f7b109d75",
 "token_type": "bearer",
 "expires_in": 4999,
 "scope": "read write trust"
 }
```

Instead I receive: Failed to load http://localhost:8088/oauth/token: Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 401.

Also when I inspect the request sent from the browser, I see that it sent an OPTIONS request and not a post.

server is running om port 8088
and client is running on port 8080

Am I missing any configuration here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference, this is how I fixed this:
I added the following bean

```
 @Configuration
 public class CorsConfig {

      @Bean
      public FilterRegistrationBean myCorsFilter() {
           UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
           CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
           config.setAllowCredentials(true);
           config.addAllowedOrigin("http://localhost:8080");
           config.addAllowedHeader("*");
           config.addAllowedMethod("*");
           source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
           FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean(new CorsFilter(source));
           bean.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
           return bean;
      }
 }
```

please note that while this gets the job done, it is recommended to configure the allowed headers and methods according to the needs of your application

Comment: FilterRegistrationBean  not present in spring 4.3 version, how could I configure?